# Why does FreeMarkers built-in "?is_string" return true for an Object?

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

If I pass an Object into the model and test it with the "?is_string" built-in, it will falsely return a true value.
Is it possible (without checking the class name) to have a proper type checks on Objects?

FreeMarker: 2.3.28

Code to reproduce:

```
public class Test {} 

// In Test Controller
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("test");
mv.addObject("test", new Test());

// In test.ftl
<#if test?is_string>
  ${test} - is a string!
</#if>

// Result
Test@455b31c - is a string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that that approach isn't really supported by FreeMarker. The Java objects are mapped to some template language values via `Configuration.objectWrapper`, and the template only sees the result of that mapping. Furthermore the template language has a different type system than Java, a simplistic one, without classes. (It was a design goal back then that the data-model is just some simple tree, and the templates will work no mater what objects are behind, as far as it still gives the same tree.) `?is_...` doesn't check the Java type, but the type according the template language. As with the usual `ObjectWrapper`-s a "generic" object (means, nothing recognized like `List`, `Map`, `Date`, etc.) can be used as a strings whose value is whatever `toString()` returns, it's a string as far as the template language is concerned. It's kind of duck typed...

A workaround I can think of is that first check the value with `?is_hash`, as that will catch the said generic objects (as they support `.`, they are hashes as well, not just strings). Or instead just check the property you expect to be present in a `Test`. Then on the "else" branch you can continue with `?is_string`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I created a helper function:
<#function isString obj>
  <#return obj?is_string && !obj?is_hash_ex>
</#function>
It returns the expected results now.